# pandas elementwise difference between two DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a pandas idiomatic way to find the difference in days between two pandas DatetimeIndex?

```
>>> d1 = pd.to_datetime(['2000-01-01', '2000-01-02'])
>>> d2 = pd.to_datetime(['2001-01-01', '2001-01-02'])
```

`-` operator is set difference, ie dates in d1 but not in d2.

```
>>> d1-d2
DatetimeIndex(['2000-01-01', '2000-01-02'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

IMO, this is not consistent with numpy and pure python behaviour. Not even pandas itself

```
>>> d2[0]-d1[0]
Timedelta('366 days 00:00:00')
```

This is what I want, but ugly.

```
>>> [d.days for d in d2.to_pydatetime() - d1.to_pydatetime()]
[366, 366]
```

Comment: `d1-d2` should be `d2-d1` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `np.subtract` directly:

```
np.subtract(d2, d1)
```

Which'll give you a TimedeltaIndex as a result:

```
TimedeltaIndex(['366 days', '366 days'], dtype='timedelta64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Then if wanted use `.days` on that.

Another possible way:

```
pd.to_timedelta(d2.values - d1.values).days
```

Which'll leave you with:

```
array([366, 366])
```

Comment: Or `(d2.values - d1.values).astype('timedelta64[D]')`

Answer (score 2):

This is because the `dtype` is `datetimeIndex` so arithmetic operations are set-wise by design, if you construct a `Series` from them then you can perform the element-wise subtraction as desired:

```
In [349]:
d1 = pd.to_datetime(['2000-01-01', '2000-01-02'])
d2 = pd.to_datetime(['2001-01-01', '2001-01-02'])
s1 = pd.Series(d1)
s2 = pd.Series(d2)
(s1-s2).abs()

Out[349]:
0   366 days
1   366 days
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: Thanks. But I hope you agree Jon's `np.subtract(d2,d1)` is nicer even though you beat him on time.

Comment: @jf328 I think it's useful to understand that this is by design and not a bug, the type returned from `to_datetime` is a datetimeIndex so arithmetic operations are set-wise, only Series, DataFrames, panels etc. behave like matrices